# Como puedo añadir un constraint a un modelo en Django q me permita validar que un campo de fecha no puede ser mayor a otro campo de fecha

Tags: django, django-models, constraints

Este es el codigo del modelo, necesito un constraint que valide que el campo `start` no puede ser mayor que el campo `end`

```
class Course(models.Model):

    def start_default():
        return datetime.date(year=int(COURSE_CHOICES[2][0][:4]), month=1, day=1)
    
    def end_default():
        return datetime.date(year=int(COURSE_CHOICES[2][0][5:]), month=12, day=31)
    
    start = models.DateField(verbose_name='inicio', 
                             auto_now=False, 
                             auto_now_add=False, 
                             unique=True, 
                             default=start_default,
                             
                            )
    
    end = models.DateField(verbose_name='fin', 
                           auto_now=False, 
                           auto_now_add=False, 
                           unique=True, 
                           default=end_default,
                          )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ("Curso")
        verbose_name_plural = ("Cursos")
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
            name='unique_date', 
            fields=['start', 'end'],
            ),
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

a ver si esto te puede ayudar, aqui chequeamos que start no puede ser mayor que end.

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.CheckConstraint(
            check=Q(start__gt=end),
            name = "unique_date"
        )
]
```